# silverstripe 3.2 htmleditorfield not saving data

Tags: silverstripe

I'm having a very strange issue with silverstripe htmleditorfield.
If I use textareafield then starts saving data, I've tried changing data type as well. But nothing works.
Here the code:

```
//DB model

private static $db = [
    'SliderHeading'      => 'Varchar(255)',
    'SliderHeadingLevel' => 'Varchar(2)',
    'SliderContent'  => 'HTMLText',
    'SliderVideoLink'    => 'Varchar(255)',
    'ContentPosition'    => "Enum('Right, Left')"
];

public function getCMSFields()
{

    $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

    $sliderContent = new HTMLEditorField('SliderContent', 'Content');
    $sliderContent->setRows(15);       

    $fields->addFieldsToTab('Root.Main',
        [

            $sliderContent,

        ]
    );

    return $fields;
}
```

Comment: You should check out [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and trim down the code in your example to just what is needed to help understand and solve your problem.

Comment: A dev/build?flush=all should fix it.